# Create Per Request Data Loaders in GraphQL Java

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am using GraphQL to create an API that queries some endpoints. Right now the way that the DataLoader is setup, the values in the cache persist across multiple web requests. As suggested in the [docs](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v11/batching/), I want to change that so that DataLoaders are scoped per request - i.e cache data from one request is not visible to another request. The docs do not explicitly give an example on how to go about doing this.

I see this link: https://github.com/graphql-java/java-dataloader/issues/19
..and I was wondering if this is still the correct/only way to go? Or is there some another way as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still the same idea.

To process a GraphQL request , you have to create a new `ExecutionInput` instance and configure its setting for every request. One of its setting is the `Context` object (It is a generic `Object` type and so you are free to define your own type). Just make sure that this `Context` object contain a `DataLoaderRegistry` and ensure that you create a new instance of `Context` with the new instance of `DataLoaderRegistry` that register a new instance of `DataLoader` to it.

Code wise, it looks likes:

```
public class MyContext {
    private DataLoaderRegistry dataLoaderRegistry;

    public MyContext(DataLoaderRegistry dataLoaderRegistry){
        this.dataLoaderRegistry = dataLoaderRegistry;
    }
}

//Process a GraphQL request

DataLoaderRegistry dataLoaderRegistry = new DataLoaderRegistry();
dataLoaderRegistry.register("fooDataLoder" , DataLoader.newDataLoader("......."));

MyContext context = new MyContext(dataLoaderRegistry);


ExecutionInput executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                .query("employees {id name department}")
                .context(context)
                .dataLoaderRegistry(context.getDataLoaderRegistry())
                .build();

 GraphQL graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build();
 ExecutionResult executionResult = graphQL.execute(executionInput);
```

A small difference is that in some later version of [graphql-java](/questions/tagged/graphql-java) , you do not need to explicitly configure `DataLoaderDispatcherInstrumentation` for the `GraphQL` like [this](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-http-example/blob/98a4a899adf4a97107aea058c079e0c1222e27cf/src/main/java/com/graphql/example/http/HttpMain.java#L122) as it will be automatically activated if it is not configured. Instead, just make sure you configure the same `dataLoaderRegistry` for the `ExecutionInput` that you set for the `Context` because `DataLoaderDispatcherInstrumentation` need to access `DataLoaderRegistry` from it.